# Resolution Problems with Intel 945GM with external monitor (iiyama proLite E2407HDS)

Tags: windows, drivers

I got a *Panasonic Toughbook CF-19* with INTEL 945GM VGA and at work I got a new monitor to use (*24" iiyama ProLite E2407HDS*) and I am using Windows XP Pro SP3.

My problem is that when I connect the screen the maximum resolution I can choose is 1680 x 1050, but the screen is widescreen and this resolution looks very odd and blurry.

Is there a way to get 1920 x 1080 (*others in the office use this resolution*) or even a smaller but proper 16:9 so it wont be that odd looking?

I know it might involve some `.inf` / registry changes.

I tried to find answer for this, already, also tried PowerStrip, without any luck.

Comment: Have you tried grabbing the driver pack from http://www.iiyama.com/gb_en/products/prolite-e2407hds-1/ ?

Comment: I did but its a pack with "all" iiyama models, which does not contains this one...